# Dynamic Bytecode Execution

Tags: java, bcel

Alright so I'm trying to write a generic string deobfuscator (Similar to what .NET has with Simple Assembly Explorer)

What I want to do is grab a method's instructions via BCEL and execute them with arguments I provide and have access to the output of that method. Is this possible to do with any existing libraries? If so, can I get some help?

Thanks

Comment: What is a string deobfuscator?

Comment: Thorbjørn: As in it will go and find every LDC with an INVOKESTATIC after it (A call to a method to decrypt the string) and decrypt/replace the string with the contents of that method AKA deobfuscating the strings in a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of BCEL and reflection/invocation could do the job. Use BCEL to get the names of the classes and methods (your `LDC`, `invokestatic` trick or something similiar) and invoke the method right after. You can do this if you put your "test classes" on the classpath. To me, there's no need to execute byte code.

---

If you have a class and a method name, it goes like this:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(yourClassName);
// either (for public methods)
Method method = clazz.getMethod(yourMethodName);
// or for protected / private methods:
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(yourMethodName, yourArgumentTypes);
method.setAccessible(true); 

// assuming the method is static
Object result = method.invoke(null, yourMethodArgs);
// otherwise: pass a object reference instead of null
// to call the method "on" that object
```

Comment: I can run the method with my arguments and access the result via reflection?